# Бот просто не включается, в консоль нечего не пишет

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Вот код, активирую через консоль, не активируется, в консоль нечего не пишет

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
from datetime import datetime


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ['$sudo '])

client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot connected')
    await client.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game("$sudo помощь"))\


@client.command()
async def пес(ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/animal/dog') # Get-запрос
    json_data = json.loads(response.text) # Извлекаем JSON

    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9900, title = 'Рандомный ПЕС') # Создание Embed'a
    embed.set_image(url = json_data['link']) # Устанавливаем картинку Embed'a
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)


@client.command()
async def HACKROBUX(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Вы успешно взломали ∞ робуксов!')

@client.command()
async def время(ctx):
    
    emb = discord.Embed( title = "Время" )

    emb.set_author( name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar_url )
    emb.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    emb.set_image(url = "")
    emb.set_thumbnail( url = 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7f/9c/62/7f9c62b4f64b30113328bc93937e8593.png')


    now_date = datetime.now()
    emb.add_field( name = 'Time', value = ' {}'.format(now_date) )

    await ctx.send( embed = emb )

@client.command()
async def помощь(ctx):
    
    emb = discord.Embed( title = "Команды бота:" )

    emb.set_author( name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar_url )
    emb.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    emb.set_image(url = "")
    emb.set_thumbnail( url = '')

    emb.add_field( name = 'Забава', value = 'HACKROBUX, время, Плюс, пес')
    emb.add_field( name = 'Модерирование', value = "kick, ban, unban, очистка")
    emb.add_field( name = 'Заметка', value = "Писать таким же регистром букв")

    await ctx.send( embed = emb )

@client.command()
async def Плюс(ctx, x: int, y: int):
    await ctx.send(x+y)

@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def очистка(ctx, count: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=count+1)
    await ctx.send(f"Было удаленно {count} сообщений")

@client.command()
async def unban(ctx, id_: int = None):
    if id_:
        banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
        member_full = bot.get_user(id=id_)
        for ban in banned_users:
            if ban.user == member_full:
                await ctx.guild.unban(ban.user)
        await ctx.send('Пользователь разбанен')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Введите айди')



@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason):
 await ctx.send("Изгоняем участника {0} по причине: {1}".format(member, reason))
 await member.kick(reason=f'{ctx.author} Выгнал {member}')


@client.command( pass_context = True )
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
@client.command()
async def Тригеред(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if not member: # if no member is mentioned
        member = ctx.author # the user who ran the command will be the member
        
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as trigSession:
        async with trigSession.get(f'https://some-random-api.ml/canvas/triggered?avatar={member.avatar_url_as(format="png", size=1024)}') as trigImg: # get users avatar as png with 1024 size
            imageData = io.BytesIO(await trigImg.read()) # read the image/bytes
            
            await trigSession.close() # closing the session and;
            
            await ctx.reply(file=discord.File(imageData, 'triggered.gif'))


@client.command()
async def embed(ctx, x: input(), y: input(), t: input()):
    
    emb = discord.Embed( title = x )

    emb.set_author( name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar_url )
    emb.set_footer( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url )
    emb.set_image(url = "")
    emb.set_thumbnail( url = '')

    emb.add_field( name = y, value = t)

    await ctx.send( embed = emb )



client.run('token')
```

в client.run токен есть, просто не показываю

Comment: Прежде чем отправлять сюда **весь** свой код, попробуйте решить проблему самостоятельно, посмотрев есть ли проблема с **минимальным примером**, который следует предоставлять на StackOverflow. В противном случае на вряд ли кому-то будет интересно разбираться со всем предоставленным кодом. Оставьте только функцию `on_ready()` и посмотрите, запускается ли бот с ней. Если нет — то исправьте код в вопросе. Если да, то добавляйте остальные части кода, пока не поймете в чем причина. На вряд ли получится помочь чем-то еще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В команде кик неправильные отступы скорее всего из за этого бот и не включаеться, правильный код внизу, надеюсь помог

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason):
    await ctx.send("Изгоняем участника {0} по причине: {1}".format(member, reason))
    await member.kick(reason=f'{ctx.author} Выгнал {member}')
```